# Conflict between facet_wrap(scales) and scale_y_continous(labels, breaks)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let there be a dataframe...

```r
library(tidyverse)

dates <- c("2019-03-01", "2019-04-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-06-01", "2019-07-01")
d <- data_frame(month = dates %>% factor(ordered = TRUE),
                subject = "Abc_14",
                taux = runif(length(dates)),
                volume = (runif(length(dates)) * 100) %>% as.integer())
d %>% glimpse()
```

```
Observations: 5
Variables: 4
$ month   <ord> 2019-03-01, 2019-04-01, 2019-05-01, 2019-06-01, 2019-07-01
$ subject <chr> "Abc_14", "Abc_14", "Abc_14", "Abc_14", "Abc_14"
$ taux    <dbl> 0.67040271, 0.85711442, 0.94608828, 0.65138723, 0.02835217
$ volume  <int> 52, 46, 33, 17, 69
```

And let there be this failing plot:

```r
d %>% 
  ggplot(aes(volume, taux)) +
  geom_density2d(size = .2) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = subject)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +

  facet_wrap(facets = vars(month), scales = "free") +

  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, breaks = seq(0, 1, .2)) +

  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

```
Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L, : argument 'nsmall' incorrect
```

It seems that there is a conflict between `facet_wrap` and `scale_y_continuous`. Excluding any of them I get a result. **Is there something I can do to keep them both?**

Without `scale_y_continous()` I get that, but I really need the percent labels:
[image]

Note: The real data frame has about 200 lines, about 30 subjects, about 10 months, with some missing combinations. It is still growing.

Comment: Could you try `labels = scales::percent_format()`.

Comment: Or `scales::percent_format(accuracy=2)`.

Comment: It works. Write an answer such that I can accept it. It is better than my `labels, breaks` solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace `scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, breaks = seq(0, 1, .2))` with something like

```
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy=2), breaks = seq(0, 1, .2))
```